# pub get error : Expected a key while parsing a block mapping

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec.yaml

[image]

[image]

I don't know what the problem is.
I tried to write multiple spaces, and all of them had errors.

Comment: `hive_generator`, `build_runner`, `http`, `flutter_lints` should all be indented 2 spaces not 3 or 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a Backspace at `flutter_lints:^2.0.0 line 67`

follow the # sign in the **66 no line** you need to align down to #